# select element with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

how can I select the following element using prototype `div#page_container h1` and after selecting it change its padding-top ? Thank you

Comment: It's all in the docs. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include [these](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/3432) .. and it should work , from this [source](http://ajaxian.com/archives/prototype-adds-css-selector-function-divpage-psummary-img)

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Prototype's $$() method allows you to select using CSS selectors, eg

```
var elmArr = $$("div#page_container h1");
```

and its setStyle method allows you to change style, eg

```
elmArr[0].setStyle({paddingTop: "4px"});
```

or

```
$$("div#page_container h1")[0].setStyle({paddingTop: "4px"});
```

Edit: I'm pretty sure the returned array is also extended by prototype, so if you had multiple h1 elements in page_container, you could do:

```
$$("div#page_container h1").each(function(elm){
    elm.setStyle({paddingTop: "4px"});
});
```

or

```
$$("div#page_container h1").invoke("setStyle",{paddingTop: "4px"});
```

to set the paddingTop of all of them

Comment: And personally, I'd use one of my last two suggestions. I use jQuery more than Prototype, and these are more in line with the philosophy of jQuery, so you're getting a little more "learning" benefit from using them

Comment: invoke takes a string as first argument : list.invoke("setStyle", myStyle);